# Can't use two screens with an Nvidia 9600GT

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors

In an effort to learn more about Ubuntu, I downloaded and installed 11.10 onto my old workstation at home. We have a second workstation that runs Windows 7 too. Both workstations are plugged into both monitors.

The Win7 one uses DVI into a HP LA2405wg 24inch monitor and DVI into a HP LP2065 20inch monitor.

The Ubuntu one uses DVI into the LP2065 and DisplayPort into the LA2405wg via a Nvidia 9600GT with 1024MB (Let me know if you need further into).

Looking in the Displays application, it only detects one screen the LP2065 but appears as "Unknown".

In the NVIDIA X Server Settings application, it detects both monitors (see below), but for the LA2405 it says Connection link disabled (see below -- might need to click it to see full screenshot).

[image: --]

How can I enable the Connection Link?

I've tried removing all NVIDIA drivers and reinstalling xorg (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68220/ubuntu-11-10-wont-boot-with-nvidia-driver-enabled)). Before I reinstalled the NVIDIA drivers, the Displays application correctly identified BOTH monitors. But wouldn't actually turn the LA2405 one on (it kept flickering to Screen Going to Sleep message and then turning on again in a loop). Installing the NVIDIA drivers, returned me to the state I started in (as described above).

A solution is greatly needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the X Server Display Configuration section, it showed the two monitors and from here I was able to enable that second monitor.

I'm sure I went through this, but I must have missed something....