# Ubuntu GUI not loading after installing nVidia Graphics Card

Tags: graphics, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System won't boot with nvidia driver enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68220/system-wont-boot-with-nvidia-driver-enabled)

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 11.10, and downloaded the nVidia GEForce 8400 GS Graphics card driver from the official site. It was a .run file, and then I entered the TTY3 interface (Alt+Ctrl+F3) and installed the graphics card as a superuser. After that, the normal GUI of Ubuntu is not coming. I did few restarts, but some lines which says "Starting Bluetooth [OK] and Checking Battery status... [OK]" something like that are displayed, then nothing happens. Please tell me what to do. Thanks

Comment: What is the output of alt ctrl f7

Answer (score 0):

Your driver is conflicting with things and stopping you from being able to boot up. What you probably want to do is boot up with the nomodeset option so that you only use the most basic programs, install the normal proprietary driver as recommended by the system if you can boot, and then you will be good to go.  I also couldn't boot with a nvidia card until I got the driver straight.

This thread looks potentially useful for you.

[System won't boot with nvidia driver enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68220/ubuntu-11-10-wont-boot-with-nvidia-driver-enabled)