# why is "saned" disabled on boot Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: scanner

I want to know why the scanner utility saned is disabled on boot and how to resolve this issue.
I have had this problem on 3 laptops and I cannot find a solution other than manually restarting the service.

Here is the error

```
saned disabled edit /etc/default/saned
```

Comment: Is it preventing logon like in the following: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126065/after-upgrading-to-12-04-i-cant-get-to-the-login-screen

Comment: No it is not. it is just blocking the scanner from working. I have to go commandline to restart it. Not good for novice users.

Answer (score 1):

As the error said, look inside /etc/default/saned :

```
# Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

# Set to yes to start saned
RUN=no

# Set to the user saned should run as
RUN_AS_USER=saned
```

If directive/variable "RUN" is set to "no", then you must change it to "yes". To do this, open /etc/default/saned file with following command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/saned
```

Set RUN=yes. Now, saned service will be started during start-up of Ubuntu, but to start the service for now, run following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/saned start
```

If you see a line similar to the below line, it means that the service is running.

```
[ ok ] Starting saned (via systemctl): saned.service.
```