# Edit file from tty1 terminal

Tags: command-line, tty, sane

I want to set the `RUN` to `yes` in the `/etc/default/saned`, as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270653/why-is-saned-disabled-on-boot-ubuntu-12-04).

Here is a snippet of the file :

```
# Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

# Set to yes to start saned
RUN=no

# Set to the user saned should run as
RUN_AS_USER=saned
```

How can I edit the saned file from within the tty1 terminal?

Answer (score 6):

Open the TTY1 (<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F1</kbd> ) and run this `sed` command :

```
sed -i '/^RUN=no$/s/no$/yes/' /etc/default/saned
```

- `/^RUN=no$/` will match the line `RUN=no`
- On that line we are substituting `no` with `yes` by `s/no$/yes/`
- `-i` option is to edit the file in place.

**Test :**

```
    $ sed '/^RUN=no$/s/no$/yes/' /etc/default/saned

    # Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

    # Set to yes to start saned
    RUN=yes

    # Set to the user saned should run as
    RUN_AS_USER=saned
```

Comment: Ok, @heemayl we have a `sed` version, therefore we need a `perl` version also =)

Comment: @A.B. `perl -i -pe 's/no/yes/ if /^RUN=no$/' /etc/default/saned` should do it :)

Comment: @MarkKCowan always done since 6 hours, see my answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Switch to tty1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login.

Edit the file with

```
sudo nano /etc/default/saned
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to leave the editor.

---

Or use the short command below …

<sub>Ok, @heemayl we have a `sed` version, therefore we need a perl version also **=)**</sub>

```
sudo perl -i -pe 's/(^RUN=)no/$1yes/' /etc/default/saned
```

---

*Example*

- The starting situation

  ```
  % cat /etc/default/saned
  # Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

  # Set to yes to start saned
  RUN=no

  # Set to the user saned should run as
  RUN_AS_USER=saned
  aboettger-VirtualBox% perl -pe 's/(^RUN=)no/$1yes/' /etc/default/saned 
  # Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

  # Set to yes to start saned
  RUN=no

  # Set to the user saned should run as
  RUN_AS_USER=saned
  ```
- The dry run

  ```
  % sudo perl -pe 's/(^RUN=)no/$1yes/' /etc/default/saned 
  # Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

  # Set to yes to start saned
  RUN=yes

  # Set to the user saned should run as
  RUN_AS_USER=saned
  aboettger-VirtualBox% perl -pe 's/(^RUN=)no/$1yes/' /etc/default/saned 
  # Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

  # Set to yes to start saned
  RUN=yes

  # Set to the user saned should run as
  RUN_AS_USER=saned
  ```
- The replacement

  ```
  % sudo perl -i -pe 's/(^RUN=)no/$1yes/' /etc/default/saned
  ```
- The final situation

  ```
  % cat /etc/default/saned                                  
  # Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

  # Set to yes to start saned
  RUN=yes

  # Set to the user saned should run as
  RUN_AS_USER=saned
  aboettger-VirtualBox% perl -pe 's/(^RUN=)no/$1yes/' /etc/default/saned 
  # Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

  # Set to yes to start saned
  RUN=yes

  # Set to the user saned should run as
  RUN_AS_USER=saned
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you just need to use one of the text-based editors, and lucky you can find many which is installed by default.

The most known/used text based editors are:

- nano(the easiest), [Learn to use](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/reu/nano.html)
- Vi(Traditional Linux editor), [Learn to use](http://www.unix-manuals.com/tutorials/vi/vi-in-10-1.html)
- pico(indeed it's just a symlink to nano)

and sure you can install tons of other text-based editors.

Now to do what you want you just need to open the file /etc/default/saned with one of your text-based editors, and then edit RUn to yes save and close.