# why is “saned” disabled on boot Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, scanner

My question is the same as

[why is "saned" disabled on boot Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270653/why-is-saned-disabled-on-boot-ubuntu-12-04)

I am trying to get an old Samsung SCX-4100 to scan to LibreOffice on 14.04.

I am a novice; the solution in the greyed out section looks promising BUT how in Terminal do I:

> look inside /etc/default/saned :
>
> ```
> # Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils
> # Set to yes to start saned
> RUN=no
> # Set to the user saned should run as
> RUN_AS_USER=saned
> ```
>
> Set RUN=yes

I entered

```
# Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils
```

into Terminal but it refuses to recognise it as a command.

Comment: I edited the answer in question #652717. If my edit is accepted, re-read the answer. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Thou shalt not start commands, but edit a file's contents.

---

To start `saned` automatically, follow the steps below:

1. Open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Open the file `/etc/default/saned` with

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/saned
   ```
3. Replace the line

   ```
   RUN=no
   ```

   with

   ```
   RUN=yes
   ```
4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file
5. and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close the editor

---

Or simply start the command

```
sudo perl -i -pe 's/RUN=no/RUN=yes/' /etc/default/saned
```

in a terminal

Comment: @Nic As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: AB, thanks, as intimated by my deleted post I would be delighted to "click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, " but there is no grey ☑ at the left of that text, sorry. There is one 12 lines up in the previous post: ticked that in case its what you'd like me to do.