# Ubuntu 12.04 cannot start, "saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned"

Tags: installation, boot

Hi. I'm new to Ubuntu and I cannot speak English very well.

I installed ubuntu 12.04 lts and it worked very well. but now it cannot start. I only see the logo an then just this text:

```
fsck de util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda7: clean, 217248/1490944 files, 1307260/5959424 blocks
skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
*Starting AppArmor profiles             [ok]
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
```

Please, does anyone have any idea what happened or know what I can do?
Many thanks from Argentina.

Comment: I see notices, no errors.

Answer (score 3):

It does look like a video driver issue that is causing plymouth and lightdm to fail to start. However, I think you'll find the machine has booted and is operational, albeit in text-only mode

You can go to a tty (terminal/commandline) by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1. You should see a prompt asking for your login an password. Login and try to re-install your graphics drivers.

If you're using NVidia, it's most likely

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

After that, run sudo reboot.

source: [After Upgrading to 12.04 I can't get to the login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126065/after-upgrading-to-12-04-i-cant-get-to-the-login-screen)