# Ubuntu 12.04 not loading after installing updates - initctl: Event failed

Tags: 12.04, boot, nvidia, apparmor

After updating my Ubuntu installation I get a blank screen when try to load it. I have dual boot with Windows which works fine.

Going into `recovery mode` -> `resume normal boot` gives me the following error:

```
swapon: /dev/disk/by-uuid/18ed9859-1325-4121-96c8-2e696055454e: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
mountall: swapon /dev/disk/by-uuid/18ed9859-1325-4121-96c8-2e696055454e [3542] terminated with status 255
mountall: Problem activating swap: /dev/disk/by-uuid/18ed9859-1325-4121-96c8-2e696055454e
modem-manager[3694]: <info> ModemManager (version 0.5.2.0) starting...

modem-manager[3694]: <info> Loaded plugin X22X

Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: user.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting AppArmor profiles                 [OK]
initctl: Event failed
```

Not sure what other info is helpful but these are some of my specs:

```
Intel Core i5-4430 3.00GHz
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 Ti
Linux 3.5.0-45-generic
Ubuntu 12.04
```

Things I've tried ([from this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126065/after-upgrading-to-12-04-i-cant-get-to-the-login-screen)):

```
# went in to CLI with CTRL+ALT+F1:
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot

# made sure all dependencies are ok:
sudo apt-get -f install
```

After doing the above I didn't get the swapon notices, but still go the AppArmor issue.

I don't know what else to check (or how to check) in order to debug this issue, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks that worked! Everything seems to be working fine now, so why do I need the nvidia drivers anyway? You can add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to remove all the packages that was related to `nvidia` by running the below command on Virtual console(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>),

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then restart your pc by running this,

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

I hope it would works.