# Unable to boot Ubuntu 14.04. initctl: Event failed

Tags: boot, 14.04

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 14.04 and it is failing.
Then I tried to boot by going in 'recovery mode' and opting 'normal boot'. The error message I am getting is :

`initctl: Event failed
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
* Starting AppArmor profiles
* Setting up X socket directories...
* speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
*Restoring resolver state...`

*and some other details too...*

After displaying this much of information, the screen goes black with just a cursor blinking. I captured the information by taking its video. As asked in another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404595/ubuntu-12-04-not-loading-after-installing-updates-initctl-event-failed), I too installed some updates the last time. And after which, the booting is failing.

My system specs:

`AMD A10-5750M APU
AMD Radeon HD 8650G + 8570M Dual Graphics`

Do I too need to uninstall my graphics driver as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404595/ubuntu-12-04-not-loading-after-installing-updates-initctl-event-failed)
Please let me know if any more information is needed from my end.

*PS : I have also installed graphics driver for my graphics card, because the default one was not working.*